# jquery cycle a child from a different random div one at a time

Tags: jquery, cycle

I have multiple content teasers on a page, where each teaser has multiple images that can be cycled through.  I want to be able to use a jquery cycle such that it selects a random teaser and cycles through to the next image, and then selects another random teaser and repeats the same.  The result should be a page of images where one image moves at a time somewhere on the page.

HTML -

```
<div class="video-slidehow">
<span class="video-thumb slideshow"><img src=""></span>
<span class="video-thumb slideshow"><img src=""></span>
<span class="video-thumb slideshow"><img src=""></span>
</div>

<div class="video-slidehow">
<span class="video-thumb slideshow"><img src=""></span>
<span class="video-thumb slideshow"><img src=""></span>
<span class="video-thumb slideshow"><img src=""></span>
<span class="video-thumb slideshow"><img src=""></span>
</div>

<div class="video-slidehow">
<span class="video-thumb slideshow"><img src=""></span>
<span class="video-thumb slideshow"><img src=""></span>
</div>
```

So it selects a random "video-slideshow" wrapper and then cycles that wrapper's "video-thumb" child to the next.  It then selects a different "video-slideshow" wrapper and cycles that "video-thumb" child to the next.

Please note that I have cleaned up this html to make it easier, each video-slideshow div does have additional parent divs etc.

I've been trying to do this by moving a class around to different divs and having that as the jquery element but that clearly doesn't appear to be the solution!

Jquery -

```
var elements = $('.video-slidehow');
$(elements[Math.floor(Math.random()*elements.length)]).addClass('someClass');


 $('.someClass').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollRight',      
    easing: 'easeInOutBack',
    speed:  700, 
    timeout: 7000, 
    after: doAfter
});


function doAfter() {
    $('.someClass').removeClass('someClass');   
       var elements = $('.video-slidehow'); 
           $(elements[Math.floor(Math.random()*elements.length)]).addClass('someClass');

        }
```

With regards the 'random' requirement.  Ideally it wouldn't be able to do the same wrapper div twice in a row.

AFTER puppybeard's answer I have attempted the following to no avail but i feel like this is starting to go down the right lines! -

```
var elements = $('.video-slidehow');

$('.video-slidehow').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollRight',      
    easing: 'easeInOutBack',
    speed:  700, 
    timeout: 7000, 
    after: doAfter
});

function doAfter() {

    $('.video-slidehow').cycle('pause');    
   $(elements[Math.floor(Math.random()*elements.length)]).cycle('resume');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Cycle's pause option on all the elements when they load.

> $('.video-thumb').cycle('pause');

When you want an item to resume, the resume function is there for that.

```
function doAfter() {


       $(elements[Math.floor(Math.random()*elements.length)]).cycle('resume');

    }
```

Comment: Ahhh.  That makes a lot more sense!  Thank you.  In context then I am guessing that I need to change the cycle element to 'video-slideshow' to load all of the slideshow divs before pausing them all and resuming them one at a time.  Should I therefore add the pause code at the start of the doAfter function to pause them all each time before resuming another one?  I am having a problem that the code in your doAfter function is breaking the jquery.  As is the pause code.  I'm trying to debug it but it simply doesn't like it.  I'll edit my question with my attempted solution.

Comment: You're right, '.video-slideshow' is the one to target.

I believe you have to inovke Cycle before you can pass commands to it.

Comment: Thanks puppybeard.  I can invoke the cycle no problem and can pause it now no problem but trying to pause it or resume it in the doAfter function as per my edited question doesn't work and just breaks the jquery across the site.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Puppybeard for sending me off in the right direction.

The solution I have used is as follows:

Firstly - create an array of all the instances to cycle between.

```
var elements = $('.video-slideshow');
```

Secondly - initiate the slideshow for all of the elements you want to cycle one at a time :

```
  $('.video-slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollRight',      
    easing: 'easeInOutBack',
    speed:  700, 
    timeout: 700
});
```

Thirdly run a function that pauses the slideshow on all elements and the resumes the slideshow for a single randomly selected element (using the previously set array).  This function needs to be rerun at a set interval to pause and resume the slideshow accordingly. I have used a setTimeout function for this.  Please note that this solution does not create a consistent pause between cycles.  I am sure a better programmer than myself can offer a more robust solution that gives that level of accuracy.

```
(function (){
    $('.video-slideshow').cycle('pause');
$(elements[Math.floor(Math.random()*elements.length)]).cycle('resume');
   setTimeout(arguments.callee, 700);
})();
```